# Image-revealing triangles in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, drawing

Say, I have some images drawn on screen, like in any average XNA project. Is it possible to make it so that only a selected array of triangles of the image is visible? Here's an example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q2a513O.png]

The red lines outline the triangles in the array. The blackness is completely hidden from view.

I tried googling and didn't find anything, so I hope this is even possible.

Comment: You can probably draw the primitives themselves with [`GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawuserindexedprimitives.aspx)

Comment: Do you have an array of triangles, and you want only some of them to show? If it's the case, you can probably just skip over them in your Draw method.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineault No, I mean having some images drawn on screen, take the on screen drawn 2d image and hide everything but what's inside the selected triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the VertexPositionTexture class.
Then use a mask consiting of a VPT for each triangle in you array to reveal the parts of your texture you want visible.
An example of how you can use it:
[enter link description here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Textures.php)

Comment: You mean as in, saving the content of the on-screen drawn image to memory, making everything black, then making the triangles have a portion of that "screenshot" as texture? That's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a mask like that, you could have a sprite that's the exact shape of the blackness (bonus if you make that shape dynamic ;)). Have it drawn in a layer above whatever you want to hide.

Comment: The triangles would be changing various times, so it would have to be a polygon of the blackness?